How long does it take to reimburse travel grant by the conference organizers?
I have participated at a funded conference in Europe, where the travel grant was sponsored by the organizers. I have submitted the form of reimbursement a month ago. Still not received the reimbursement.
I am thinking to email them but I am not sure it is early to enquire about the reimbursement.
Please share your experiences about the timing of reimbursement.
Thanks

In my experience most large organisations work on a 30-day billing cycle, so you can usually expect to receive payment within 30 days of submitting your invoice. Smaller organisations are sometimes much less organised and can be very fast or very, very slow.

In my experience, getting reimbursed within a month happens, but is rare. If it takes longer than three months, you definitely should inquire.
The organizers will probably have to do some paperwork and forward it to their finance people, who'll check the paperwork and eventually initiate the payment. However, for some reason many universities then don't make the payment immediately, but do all payments once per month or so. This means that it will take a long time even if everything goes smooth, but there are also various places where stuff can get stuck.
I don't think there is anything wrong with a polite inquiry already after a month, in particular if being out of pocket is problematic for you.

Thanks for the answer

That is impossible to answer, as it strongly depends: personally, I had an organization reimburse me after 1 week, in another case it took 11 months. No other way but politely asking the reimbursement organization for the status, maybe ask if there are documents missing from your side.
